# Cannot access the Kafka Broker from inside the Kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a kafka broker and a spring boot application in my Kubernetes cluster. They are running on their own containers.

The spring boot application is a message producer. It needs to access the kafkabroker to send the messages. But it couldn't access the Kafka broker by providing the Kafka's servicename:port in the producers bootstrap.servers

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Zookeper and KafkaBroker configuration in yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper-service
  name: zookeeper-service
  namespace: mynamespace-k8s
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: zookeeper-port
      port: 2181
      nodePort: 30181
      targetPort: 2181
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: zookeeper
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: mynamespace-k8s
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: zookeeper
          ports:
            - containerPort: 2181
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-broker
  name: kafka-service
  namespace: mynamespace-k8s
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka-broker
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kafka-broker
  name: kafka-broker
  namespace: mynamespace-k8s
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-broker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-broker
    spec:
      hostname: kafka-broker
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: KAFKA_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
          value: "9092"
        - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
          value: kafka-service.mynamespace-k8s
        - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
          value: zookeeper-service.mynamespace-k8s:2181
        - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
          value: "1"
        image: wurstmeister/kafka
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: kafka-broker
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
```

My springboot application conf in yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: locationmanager-service
  namespace: mynamespace-k8s
  labels:
     app: locationmanager
spec:
  selector:
    app: locationmanager
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32588
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: locationmanager-deployment
  namespace: mynamespace-k8s
  labels:
    app: locationmanager
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: locationmanager
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: locationmanager
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: locationmanager
        image: aef/locmanager:latest
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8081
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "1000m"
          requests:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        env:
          - name: CONFIG_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
            value: kafka-service.mynamespace-k8s:9092
```

Spring boot's bootstrap.server in application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers= ${CONFIG_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
```

When springboot application tries to create a topic, I receive the exception below:

```
2022-07-07 10:51:50,078 ERROR o.s.k.c.KafkaAdmin [main] Could not configure topics
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Timed out waiting to get existing topics; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$5(KafkaAdmin.java:275) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar!/:2.8.4]
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1337) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.checkPartitions(KafkaAdmin.java:254) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar!/:2.8.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.addOrModifyTopicsIfNeeded(KafkaAdmin.java:240) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar!/:2.8.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.initialize(KafkaAdmin.java:178) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar!/:2.8.4]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaAdmin.java:145) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar!/:2.8.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:972) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar!/:2.6.6]
    at com.trendyol.locationmanager.LocationManagerApplication.main(LocationManagerApplication.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[locationmanager.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[locationmanager.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[locationmanager.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[locationmanager.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1886) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2021) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-clients-3.0.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$5(KafkaAdmin.java:257) ~[spring-kafka-2.8.4.jar!/:2.8.4]
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: 1) Please show the log output from the `ProducerConfig` when the app starts 2) You might want to remove the space after the equals in your property file... I'd also strongly recommend that you use a Kafka k8s Operator and/or Helm Chart rather than building/configuring your own

Comment: I abandoned wurstmeister/kafka and used Bitnami and Helm. https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-scalable-kafka-zookeeper-cluster-kubernetes/                                                                                                                     It works. Thanks for help. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your configuration, which are leading to the services not working correctly:

1. The `zookeeper-service` is of type `NodePort`. Therefore, there is no need to specify the `port` parameter. The traffic will be received on `nodePort: 30181` and forwarded to the `targetPort: 2181`.
2. The `kafka-broker` service is not specifying any `targetPort` parameter. The service is of `ClusterIP` type by default which requires this parameter. You are receiving traffic on `port: 9092` but you're not forwarding it to any pods. You need to add `targetPort: 9092` which is the value of your `KAFKA_PORT` environment variable. This will correctly forward the incoming traffic to the right `kafka-service` pods.
3. The springboot application `locationmanager` is of type `Loadbalancer` therefore, there is no need to specify the `nodePort` parameter. Remove it. Additionally, the service is receiving traffic on `port: 8080` and forwards it to the pods on `targetPort: 8080`. This is incorrect, since your application deployment exposes `containerPort: 8081` instead of `8080`.

Fixing these configuration issues will fix your problem.